# Capitalizing technology names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, what's the best way to ensure a technology name is properly capitalized? For example, if I have the following:

- `"javascript"`
- `"ruby on rails"`
- `"html5"`
- `"ios"`

Then I would expect them to be capitalized as:

- `"JavaScript"`
- `"Ruby on Rails"`
- `"HTML5"`
- `"iOS"`

Using `technology.capitalize` yeilds:

- `"Javascript"`
- `"Ruby On Rails"`
- `"Html5"`
- `"Ios"`

Comment: I think making your own search and replace for things like HTML, iOS, RoR, etc is the only way to go

Comment: Ruby is not an Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping somebody had done the hard work for me and had a prepopulated the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` module with common technologies.

Comment: @LandonSchropp  They have, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use Rails ActiveSupport's [acronym](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym) method to add your list of words to the Inflections

Specifically you would add an `acronym` call for each of your custom words in your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'JavaScript'
  ...
end

"javascript".underscore.camelize #=> "JavaScript"
```

Comment: Awesome. That'll work. Thanks!